# Animation in beamer stopping at the end?

Tags: beamer, animations, multimedia

I'm working on a beamer presentation where I have many animations to show.
I have `*.avi` videos and I'm using the `multimedia` package:

```
\movie[height=XXpt,width=XX,poster]{\includegraphics[height=XXpt,width=XXpt]{image.png}}{video.avi}
```

with this command I get the image on the slide, and after clicking it the video starts. Once finished playing, on the slide reappers the initial image.

My question is: is there a way to make the video stop on its last frame? Or to put the last frame as an image that will appear automatically at the end of the video?

I tried to use the 'open' option, and it works, but then I have to click elsewhere to go on with the slides and the presentation.. can I avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: Which PDF viewer on which OS do you use?

Comment: Adobe reader on windows seven

Comment: Then you can use the `media9` package. It doesn't rewind to the first frame after reaching the end.

Comment: Thanks.. now I'm having trouble installing the media9 packages.. sigh

Comment: This should be easy with MiKTeX or TeXLive-2013.

Comment: I managed. Now it works just fine! Thank you!